# Meteor Mobile App cannot connect to server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, mobile

I'm having a series of issues connecting to my server using android, ios and iOS simulator. After several days of off again and on again searching for a way to resolve this. I've gotten closer each time but still cannot fully connect. I have Iron:Router and can go to any page that doesn't require logging in but once I attempt to register or login it 'freezes' and in the debugging process it says it cannot connect.

## Attempted

### 1. Specific DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION

in /server/lib/config.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    var theURL = "http://myUrl.com:3000";

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
        theURL = "http://101.ipaddress.0.0:3000";
    }

    Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = theURL;
    process.env.ROOT_URL = theURL;
    process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL = theURL;
    process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL = theURL;
    process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = theURL;

});
```

After some tinkering with these, it relayed me to a CORS issue afterwards. Which I resolved by doing

### 2. CORS and App.access

in mobile-config.js

```
App.accessRule('http://*');
App.accessRule('https://*');
```

This then brought me to another error that was associated with iOS security transport which is newer from xcode 8 I believe? I resolved this by

### 3. Altering App Transport Security Settings

in xCode the info tab: under App Transport Security added "Allow Arbitrary Loads": "true"

[image]

### Suggested steps

I also found a nice little piece that will console log connection status.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.autorun(function () {
    var stat;
    if (Meteor.status().status === "connected") {
        stat = 'lime'
    }else if (Meteor.status().status === "connecting") {
        stat = 'yellow'
    }else {
        stat = 'red';
    }
    Session.set('status',stat);
  });
}
        
console.log(Session.get('status'));
```

This is associated with the register button and every time it's clicked it just fires the status. It's always been 'red'.

Safari debugger says I cannot connect.

## Steps taken to connect

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server 101.ipaddress:3000
```

then I click run button. I have read up on hot code push issues and will commonly delete '.meteor/local/bundler-cache' && 'cordova-build'

I've come to a roadblock and would love some assistance/suggestions on what would be a next fix (or maybe I'm fundamentally skipping something which would be terribly annoying but joyful at the same time).

#### Extra info

Meteor versions tried 1.2.1 & 1.3
mup.json

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "101.ipaddress.0.1",
      "username": "username",
      //"password": "password",
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      // WARNING: Keys protected by a passphrase are not supported
      "pem": "ssh/directory",
      "pem": "ssh/directory",
      "env": {}
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB on the server. Does not destroy the local MongoDB on future setups
  "setupMongo": true,

  // Application name (no spaces).
  "appName": "AppName",

  // Location of app (local directory). This can reference '~' as the users home directory.
  // i.e., "app": "~/Meteor/my-app",
  // This is the same as the line below.
  "app": "/directory/to/app",

  // Configure environment
  // ROOT_URL must be set to your correct domain (https or http)
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://domainNameURL.com",
    "MOBILE_ROOT_URL": "http://domainNameURL.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment.
  // Before mup checks that, it will wait for the number of seconds configured below.
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 60,

  // show a progress bar while uploading. 
  // Make it false when you deploy using a CI box.
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

Comment: you aren't able to make a http request ?

Comment: I'm not able to 'register' or 'login' using a mobile device or their respective emulators. I can do so on browser though. So it's a DDP connection issue I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to replicate the errors on a new build using version 1.2.1.

However what may have been causing some problems:

***[ip]:[port]*** is not how I am actually testing the connection. The most successful way for me to build the app and have it work on devices and emulators was to

```
meteor build <directory> ios --mobile-server <ipaddress>
```

Note the absence of [port].

Also when I build for apple I use

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server 101.ipaddress.1
```

And then click on product>archive

For deployment I'm using mupx
    mupx deploy

Meteor's deploy/compiling process may be a mess as the first time I attempted to upload the apk it gave me the actual number I had set in mobile-config.js i.e. version 0.0.7 but after that each attempt concatenated an 8 at the end. i.e. if I had 0.0.1 it was 18, and 0.0.2 it was 28. This was even with

```
App.setPreference('android-versionCode', '7');
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '23')
```

Set. Which is disappointing because it seems like such a fast build for web apps. I was excited to test it on mobile on to come across so many issues.

So in summary. Built a new meteor 1.2 app. Then added manually all of my packages. After that I copy and pasted my client, lib and server folders. I can now register and login and it's showing an active connection using the coding snippet above.

Comment: Hi Cody, meteor build <directory> ios --mobile-server <ipaddress> does not give you error? I got error --mobile-server is not valid parameter.

Answer (score 1):

While my answer probably doesn't solve the root of your problem, it hopefully helps you in the debug process.

Your postet snippet to show the current connected status is not reactive. The `console.log(Session.get('status'));` is not in a reactive context, meaning it doesn't update on changes of the Session variable. That's why it just logs the inital value `red`.
Change the code to the following to make it reactive:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.autorun(function () {
    var stat;
    if (Meteor.status().status === "connected") {
        stat = 'lime'
    }else if (Meteor.status().status === "connecting") {
        stat = 'yellow'
    }else {
        stat = 'red';
    }
    console.log('status', stat);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I had put the code in a template event so you were without context. Also, for some reason a new build of meteor 1.2.1 is able to connect, so I'm adding 4 packages at a time to see which one may be causing the issue my initial guess was iron router but that doesn't seem to be the case.